# Is there a disadvantage to being higher level in low trophy arenas?

Tags: clash-royale

I like to donate cards to my clan for the gold and exp, but is there a disadvantage to leveling up while still in lower level arenas? I donate often so I am almost level 7 and only in Arena 4/5. Is there a drawback to being such a high level in a lower level Arena?

Comment: @DJPirtu is right, the only in game effect is the strength of your structures, out of game however it has a negative reputation effect; essentially being stronger than your opponents should make it inherently easier to win (and thus level up... to a point at least).

Comment: Note - I am not criticising, just highlighting a possibility that people 'may' think

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your level *only* affects the HP and damage of your towers. There is no other effect of your level.

As you can see, there isn't any disadvantage to having a high level. This applies to all arenas.

It may also have a demoralizing effect on your opponent, if they're level or two lower. (Less on later on where levels even out and people realize that the cards and strategies play much larger role than a 100 or so more HP on the tower.)

Comment: Thanks. I was curious if SuperCell had put a system in place similar to Clash of Clans. In CoC, if you leveled up your town hall, you received less resources from battling lower level town halls.

Comment: @wizloc As far as I know, the only resources you get from battles are _chests_ and _trophies_. The first you get based on arena played on (chest level) and where you are at chest rotation (silver, gold or magic). The latter is determined by the difference in _trophies_.

Answer (score 0):

It's not about any of that. What does it require to level up? It requires large amounts of upgrades, so if you fight someone who's a high level than you then they have stronger cards. And sometimes tier cards; meaning someone could bring hog rider from arena 4 to 3 and have an advantage. Many higher level players are losing their place in clash, and cause others to lose because they still have higher tier cards. It's a huge domino effect.

Comment: flagging as not an answer as you do not address the question, you skirted around the topic but did not address the question of 'is there a drawback'

Comment: I did, but if you can't read between the lines I'll type in a way you can understand. No, you have a huge advantage! Your cards are a higher level and you probably have a larger variety.

Comment: Sorry, but as I mentioned in the question I am leveling up by donating cards, not upgrading them.

Comment: I don't see how any of this is a disadvantage to the _higher level_ player.